# ElasticSearch - Combine filters & Composite Query to get unique fields combinations

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

Well.. I am quite "newb" regarding ES so regarding aggregation... there is no words in the dictionary to describe my level regarding it :p

Today I am facing an issue where I am trying to create a query that should execute something similar to a SQL DISTINCT, but among filters. I have this document given (of course, an abstraction of the real situation):

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "createdAt": 1626783747,
  "updatedAt": 1626783747,
  "isAvailable": true,
  "kind": "document",
  "classification": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "a_name_for_id_1"
  },
  "structure": {
    "material": "cartoon",
    "thickness": 5
  },
  "shared": true,
  "objective": "stackoverflow"
}
```

As all the data of the above document can vary, I however have some values that can be redundant, such as `classification.id`, `kind`, `structure.material`.

So, in order to fullfit my requirements, I would like to "group by" these 3 fields in order to have a unique combination of each. If we go deeper, with the following data, I should get the following possibilities:

```
[{
        "id": "1",
        "createdAt": 1626783747,
        "updatedAt": 1626783747,
        "isAvailable": true,
        "kind": "document",
        "classification": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "a_name_for_id_1"
        },
        "structure": {
            "material": "cartoon",
            "thickness": 5
        },
        "shared": true,
        "objective": "stackoverflow"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "createdAt": 1626783747,
        "updatedAt": 1626783747,
        "isAvailable": true,
        "kind": "document",
        "classification": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "a_name_for_id_2"
        },
        "structure": {
            "material": "iron",
            "thickness": 3
        },
        "shared": true,
        "objective": "linkedin"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "createdAt": 1626783747,
        "updatedAt": 1626783747,
        "isAvailable": false,
        "kind": "document",
        "classification": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "a_name_for_id_2"
        },
        "structure": {
            "material": "paper",
            "thickness": 1
        },
        "shared": false,
        "objective": "tiktok"
    },
    {
        "id": "4",
        "createdAt": 1626783747,
        "updatedAt": 1626783747,
        "isAvailable": true,
        "kind": "document",
        "classification": {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "a_name_for_id_3"
        },
        "structure": {
            "material": "cartoon",
            "thickness": 5
        },
        "shared": false,
        "objective": "snapchat"
    },
    {
        "id": "5",
        "createdAt": 1626783747,
        "updatedAt": 1626783747,
        "isAvailable": true,
        "kind": "document",
        "classification": {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "a_name_for_id_3"
        },
        "structure": {
            "material": "paper",
            "thickness": 1
        },
        "shared": true,
        "objective": "twitter"
    },
    {
        "id": "6",
        "createdAt": 1626783747,
        "updatedAt": 1626783747,
        "isAvailable": false,
        "kind": "document",
        "classification": {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "a_name_for_id_3"
        },
        "structure": {
            "material": "iron",
            "thickness": 3
        },
        "shared": true,
        "objective": "facebook"
    }
]
```

based on the above, I should get the following results in the "buckets":

- document 1 cartoon
- document 2 iron
- document 2 paper
- document 3 cartoon
- document 3 paper
- document 3 iron

Of course, for the sake of this example (and to make it easier, I yet don't have any duplicates)

However, on top of that, I need some "pre-filters" as I only want:

- Documents that are available `isAvailable=true`
- Documents'structure's thickness should range between 2 and 4 included: `2 >= structure.thickness >= 4`
- Document's that are shared `shared=true`

I should so then get only the following combinations compared to the first set of results:

- *document 1 cartoon* `-> not a valid result, thickness > 4`
- **document 2 iron**
- *document 2 paper* `-> not a valid result, isAvailable != true`
- *document 3 cartoon* `-> not a valid result, thickness > 4`
- *document 3 cartoon* `-> not a valid result, thickness < 2`
- *document 3 iron* `-> not a valid result, isAvailable != true`

If you're still reading, well.. thanks! xD

So, as you can see, I need all the possible combination of this field regarding the static pattern `kind <> classification_id <> structure_material` that are matching the filters regarding `isAvailable, thickness, shared`.

Regarding the output, the hits doesn't matter to me as I don't need the documents but only the combination `kind <> classification_id <> structure_material` :)

Thanks for any help :)

Max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to a colleague, I could finally get it working as expected!

**QUERY**

```
GET index-latest/_search
{
   "size": 0,
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "filter": [
            {
               "term": {
                  "isAvailable": true
               }
            },
            {
               "range": {
                  "structure.thickness": {
                     "gte": 2,
                     "lte": 4
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "term": {
                  "shared": true
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "aggs": {
      "my_agg_example": {
         "composite": {
            "size": 10,
            "sources": [
               {
                  "kind": {
                     "terms": {
                        "field": "kind.keyword",
                        "order": "asc"
                     }
                  }
               },
               {
                  "classification_id": {
                     "terms": {
                        "field": "classification.id",
                        "order": "asc"
                     }
                  }
               },
               {
                  "structure_material": {
                     "terms": {
                        "field": "structure.material.keyword",
                        "order": "asc"
                     }
                  }
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

The given result is then:

```
{
   "took": 11,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "skipped": 0,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": {
         "value": 1,
         "relation": "eq"
      },
      "max_score": null,
      "hits": []
   },
   "aggregations": {
      "my_agg_example": {
         "after_key": {
            "kind": "document",
            "classification_id": 2,
            "structure_material": "iron"
         },
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": {
                  "kind": "document",
                  "classification_id": 2,
                  "structure_material": "iron"
               },
               "doc_count": 1
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

So, as we can see, we get the following bucket:

```
{
    "key": {
        "kind": "document",
        "classification_id": 2,
        "structure_material": "iron"
    },
    "doc_count": 1
}
```

> **Note**: Be careful regarding the type of your field.. putting `.keyword` on *classification.id* was resulting to no results in the buckets... `.keyword` should be use only on types such as string (as far as I understood, correct me if I am wrong)

As expected, we have the following result (compared to the initial question):

- **document 2 iron**

> **Note**: Be careful, the order of the elements within the `aggs.<name>.composite.sources` does play a role in the returned results.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can got with **Cardinatily** aggregations with your existing filters.Please check this url and let me know if you have any queries.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I tried your approach but without success.. `Text fields are not optimised for operations that require per-document field data like aggregations and sorting, so these operations are disabled by default`